# Receiving Partial Response Body Using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, json, asynchttpclient

I'm writing a REST Service Consumer class using `AsyncHttpClient`. The Service returns a `JSON` Response String with lot of extra data that I don't need. I'm only interested in specific part of the received response.

For Example, consider the following `JSON Response`:

```
{
    "decisions": {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar"
    }
    "internals": {
        "foobar": "foobar"
    }
}
```

Now, I'm only interested in `decisions` object and do not want to waste time and memory in fetching the `internals` as this is huge in actual response and I do not need it.

Is it possible using the `AsyncHttpClient`? How shall I achieve this?

Here is the code snippet of my class:

```
AsyncHttpClient c = new AsyncHttpClient();
Future<String> f = c.prepareGet("http://www.foo.org/ba").execute(new AsyncHandler<String>() {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public STATE onStatusReceived(HttpResponseStatus status) throws Exception {
        return STATE.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public STATE onHeadersReceived(HttpResponseHeaders h) throws Exception {
         return STATE.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public STATE onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
         /* What shall I write here? */
         return STATE.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public String onCompleted() throws Exception {
         return bytes.toString("UTF-8");
    }

    @Override
    public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
        /* TODO : Throw Exception */
    }
});

String bodyResponse = f.get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is built on top of TCP, so it's inherently chunked. You get notified of those chunks of **bytes** in `onBodyPartReceived`. Those chunks's length is typically one [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit).

What you're trying to achieve would require that:

- You know for sure that what you're looking for is in the first chunk
- You know for sure that you won't get dandling bytes that don't map to your character encoding (a single char encoded in 2 or more bytes, and spanned over 2 consecutive chunks). You can only know that for sure if your encoding is US-ASCII, not UTF-8.
- You can parse your partial response body with something else than a JSON parser (regex probably) as you won't get a valid JSON payload.

If you can make sure all those assumptions are valid, you can do this extraction in `onBodyPartReceived` and return `STATE.ABORT`.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks :)